# Viewing the Local Storage of a HTTP website that now redirects to HTTPS

Tags: google-chrome, browser, http, https, local-storage

The [Notepad website](http://browserpad.org) I've been using lost all of the data that I had kept on it. Not only that, it turns out the snapshots I was downloading were all empty! Unfortunately, I had important data on it, and I'm really trying hard to fetch it back.

From my investigation, I've noticed that the website was saved as HTTP in my session manager, but today, it automatically redirects to HTTPS. It also saves the data in Local Storage, and turns out, Local Storage does not follow from HTTP to HTTPS, being considered two different websites.

So in theory, my Local Storage should still be there, under the old address. Which means, I have a couple of ways to solve my problem:

- View the Local Storage directly. Unfortunately, <kbd>F12</kbd> only works on accessible websites, and I haven't been able to find a way to open the Local Storage files in a readable format.
- Transfer the HTTP Local storage to HTTPS. I had found [this script](https://gist.github.com/Draknek/1719f7d01e43f233836e8b2abe6b2ae8#file-savepuzzles-js) which was designed for another website that faced the same issue, but after changing the addresses, it still didn't work.
- Prevent the redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. The only solution I found for that asked to clear the cache, and I'm scared that it might erase the very data I'm trying to retrieve.

Does anyone have a working solution to my problem? I am using Google Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: You could use your hosts file to redirect `browserpad.org` to `127.0.0.1` and run your own [HTTP server](https://cesanta.com/) locally. That may allow you to trick the browser into thinking its connected to the actual site over HTTP and use the developer tools to browse the local storage. I've never tried this before though.